# XSLT, get the most frequent instead of the first element

Tags: xml, xslt

So I've got an XML file and I'm trying to find, pretty much per attribute on the references, for some elements, the value of the most common element.

Now, the understanding I have, is that the below code should sort the values by value-count, then select the first element of the sorted node. That doesn't happen for some reason. It just selects the first child/element value of the unsorted variant.

So, something must be glaringly obviously off...but after multiple hours, I'm still left heart-broken at the prospect of not figuring this one out.

Can any SO Guru point me in the right direction?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
                <h1>bgy summary</h1>
                <h2>jal articles</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Number of jal articles</li>
                    <dd>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(bgy/reference[@refType='jal'])"/>
                    </dd>
                    <li>Most frequent jal</li>
                    <dd>
                        <xsl:for-each select="bgy/reference[@refType='jal']">
                            <xsl:sort select="count(jal)"
                                        data-type="number"
                                        order="descending"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                <xsl:value-of select="jal"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </dd>
                    <li>Most frequent per</li>
                    <dd>
                        <xsl:for-each select="bgy/reference[@refType='jal']">
                            <xsl:sort select="count(per)"
                                        data-type="number"
                                        order="descending"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                <xsl:value-of select="per"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </dd>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<bgy>
    <reference refType="jal">
        <as>Heidi B</as>
        <year>2018</year>
        <title>Title-H-93</title>
        <jal>jal-q</jal>
        <volume>2</volume>
        <issue>1</issue>
        <per>Springer</per>
        <doi>117/659</doi>
        <date>01/02/2022</date>
    </reference>
    <reference refType="jal">
        <as>Heidi B</as>
        <year>2004</year>
        <title>Title-D-88</title>
        <jal>jal-p</jal>
        <volume>4</volume>
        <issue>3</issue>
        <per>ACM</per>
        <doi>291/1750</doi>
        <date>04/04/2022</date>
    </reference>
    <reference refType="jal">
        <as>Heidi B</as>
        <year>2007</year>
        <title>Title-D-77</title>
        <jal>jal-p</jal>
        <volume>2</volume>
        <issue>5</issue>
        <per>ACM</per>
        <doi>1375/420</doi>
        <date>04/01/2022</date>
    </reference>
</bgy>
```

output I am getting:

```
bgy summary
jal articles

    Number of jal articles
        3
    Most frequent jal
        jal-q
    Most frequent per
        Springer
```

output I am expecting:

```
bgy summary
jal articles

    Number of jal articles
        3
    Most frequent jal
        jal-p
    Most frequent per
        ACM
```

Comment: We need to see a schema for the XML input or a small but representative sample to tell whether the XPath expressions make sense.

Comment: on it. does this help @MartinHonnen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds as if you want to group the elements by jal e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="bgy/reference[@refType='jal']" group-by="jal"><xsl:sort select="count(current-group())" descending="yes"/><xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each-group>`

Comment: it sounds like you're on to something. However, trying the above out on the online w3schools resource for a quick test, there is no response. Meaning something is going off mark.

Comment: @Uvar, if the question presents code with `xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"` I will certainly use XSLT 2 in the answer. If you then tell me you expect w3schools to run the XSLT 2 code, sorry, but use an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9 or 10 or Saxon JS 2 or sides like xsltransform.net or xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net to test and run XSLT 2.

Comment: Just goes to show how much out of my depth I am here.               If you have the patience to present a XSLT 1 solution as well, I'd be very grateful, but I realize the question is ill-posed by having my declaration and what I'm able to verify mismatch

Comment: using xlstransform.net , I see that everything is at it should be; and I need more schooling if I ever wish to do anything with this in a proper setting.  Many thanks for your help, Martin!